# Expressing spherical functions with zonal harmonics

Tags: legendre-polynomials, spherical-harmonics

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm d}$First time using StackExchange, so please excuse any mistakes:

My goal is to express functions on the sphere as a sum of zonal harmonics.

I've spent a while with the simpler case, where we have a function of one variable and we want to express it with a sum of Legendre polynomials, and have gotten that to work: For example, if we have the function $f(x) = sin(\pi x)$, we can then use the fact that
$$ f(x) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty a_l P_l(x)$$
where $P_l(x)$ is the Legendre polynomial of order $l$ to first find coefficients 
$$ a_l = \frac{2l+1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 f(x) P_l(x) dx $$

Numerically, my approach to build approximation function $g(x)$ is to first find my coefficients with the equation
$$a_l = \frac{2l+1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} f(\cos(x))P_l(\cos(x))\sin(x) \d x $$
and then to express
$$ g(x) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty a_l P_l(x)$$

As far as I can tell, this has been working fine. My problem is when I now have equations of the form $f(\phi, \theta)$. I'm trying to use the same approach as above, but the details are eluding me: such an attempt as the following yields horribly wrong results:
$$a_l = \frac{2l+1}{2} \int_{0}^\pi \int_{0}^{\pi}f(\phi, \theta)P_l(\cos\theta)P_l(\cos\phi)\sin(\theta) \sin(\phi)\d\theta \d\phi$$
$$ g(\phi, \theta) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty a_l P_l(\cos \theta) P_l(\cos \phi)$$

Am I simply making mistakes in my computation, or is there something wrong in this approach for spherical functions? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at spherical harmonics? Its not in the question whether you are aware of them, or if there is some reason you cannot use them.

Comment: In spherical coordinates $\theta$ and $\phi$ don't have the same range. The azimuthal angle ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$ while the other angle ranges from $0$ to $\pi$. This is one thing your integral fails to take into account.

Comment: The spherical harmonics handle this by working with functions of the form $P_l(\cos\theta) e^{im\phi}$

Comment: Hi! I'm aware that spherical harmonics exist, but I didn't want to overcomplicate the problem quite yet. Eventually I want to move onto higher-dimensional spheres, but if I could simply express something like the polynomial $x^2 + xy$ (over the 2-sphere) for now, I would be happy. Does this necessitate spherical harmonics, or are zonal harmonics still possible in this case?

Comment: Ah I see: if I instead modified my equation for the constant to be: $$ a_{lm} = \frac{2l+1}{2} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} f(\phi, \theta) P_l cos(\theta) e^{im\phi} d\phi d\theta $$, would that be fine? I understand that spherical harmonics have a degree m as well as an order l: how would I select this m? Would I have to take $$ g(\phi, \theta) = \sum_{l = 0}^\infty \sum_{m = -l}^l a_{lm} Y_l^m (\phi, \theta) $$ instead?

Comment: Those look basically correct in spirit; I am not sure about the $(2l+1)/2$ as the normalization constant. I would check this to get the details ironed out. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics